# Using Enterprise Architect to create a Sequence Diagram for a C# WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram

I am trying to use EA 10 to generate sequence diagrams for our code.

I found [this tutorial](http://blog.lieberlieber.com/2012/03/13/tutorial-nunit-and-sequence-diagram-recording-in-enterprise-architect-9-3/) but it is for EA 9 and uses a console application to attach to.

How can this be done for EA 10 and for a Wcf service?

I tried attaching to the WcfTestClient but couldn't get that to work

Answer (score 0):

After you add Recording Markers in the source code you need to run the WCF service that was built in debug mode and then attach to it using **Attach To Process** which you can find in Analyzer  -> Recorder and then clicking the down arrow on the recorder button.

**If this doesn't work...**

What I did with a Windows Service application was to create a Console Application that called the same code as the Windows Service.  Since you are using WCF it should be trivial to host the WCF service in a console application.

Once you have the console application you can set up the Execution Analyzer to Debug the console application and then your Recording Markers should be hit.